# How to enable php extensions with PHP 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I upgraded my php5 to php 7, after that i am getting following error  while i am trying to install drupal 7.

[image]

I already tried to search and enable the "PHP Extension" findings are to install "apt-get install php5-gd" but mine is php7.

Comment: Run `apt-cache search php7-*` to find out the name of extension you need,something like `php7.1-gd` then `apt-get install php7.1-gd`

Comment: Thanks gd is installed successfully now. But still its showing the same error :(

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: oops, now its working. Thanks @Mihai

Comment: how does drupal 7 run with PHP7 ? what issues did you run into?

Comment: @Mihai answer worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove `php7.1-gd` and install `php-7.0gd`:

```
sudo apt-get remove php7.1-gd -y
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd -y
```

Good luck! ;)

Comment: For folks running PHP7.1 with D7, this answer is best! You must remove 7.1 and install 7.0 for the error to go away (restart apache also).

Comment: Same for PHP7.2. Removing `php7.2-gd` is not necessary. Just install `php7.0-gd` alongside it.